# Why does "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" appear after I run my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, matplotlib

I'm new with python. I learn it myself and figure out what happen but now, I'm really stuck. Please help me to figure out my problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

x = [-0.006,-0.005,-0.004,-0.003,-0.002,-0.001,0,0.001,0.002,0.003,0.004,0.005,0.00]
y = [220*(1 - (0.85*math.exp(-math.pi**2/math.log(2)*(x*0.53*10**-9/759.5*10**-9)**2)))]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('optical path difference')
plt.ylabel('coincidence counts in 3 min')

plt.show()
```

After run it, it returns an error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

How do I need to change my code such that I can multiply the list `x` with a float?

Comment: For the record, there are a bazillion variations on this problem you could have checked, most of them with the exact error message in the title. Please look at the suggested related questions first next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot multiply a list with a float value. While lists can be "multiplied" with an integer, this would not help you here.

Instead you may use `numpy`. A numpy array can be multiplied by a single number or another numpy array.

```
[1,2,3] * 3                           # [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
[1,2,3] * 3.3                         # can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
np.array([1,2,3]) * 3                 # [3 6 9]
np.array([1,2,3]) * np.array([1,2,3]) # [1 4 9]
```

So the solution here is to use make  `x` a numpy array first. You then also have to remove the square brackets in `y`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [-0.006,-0.005,-0.004,-0.003,-0.002,-0.001,0,0.001,0.002,0.003,0.004,0.005,0.006]
x = np.array(x)
y = 220*(1 - (0.85*np.exp(-np.pi**2/np.log(2)*(x*0.53e-9/759.5e-9)**2)))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('optical path difference')
plt.ylabel('coincidence counts in 3 min')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a Python `list`. `x*0.53` is non-sensical (sequence multiplication for anything but `numpy` types means "repeat sequence that many times", and it's a discrete multiplier, you can't take the first 53% of the sequence).

Did you mean to convert `x` to a `numpy` array or something? Or process each element individually?

Comment: the x is a value from -0.006 until 0.006, I want to substitute it into the y formula automatically when it run.